# SVN where is the path of files

Tags: svn, ssh, centos

I created a svn repository on centos 6.6 
[My repository](http://190.210.186.23/repository/mgcerrajeria/trunk/)

```
<Location /repository>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/svn

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authorization Realm"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
  Require valid-user

</Location>
```

I'm able tu use all the funcionts but i cant see for example the page test.php in my centos server

i tried to locate trunk branch and tag but can't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the cpath located in /yourrepo/db/resvpos/0/x